# Odd, different outcome for same function in different project

Tags: android, udp

The **UdpServer activity** is from project downloaded from **Web** and **Mainacitivity** is from the project I created.    The issue when I step through the code `ds.receive` inside the `runUdpServer`   the one `UdpServer activity` runs OK, it waiting for data to come in.

However the `ds.receive` inside the `MainActivity(my created project)` when I step `ds.receive` it immediately go to error finally block,(unable to find source issue) and deallocated.

*Why 2 different behaviors for the same pierce of codes. I don't know what some hidden properties inside the downloaded version **UdpServer activity** that enable it to run successfully and mine failed*.

```
public class UdpServer extends Activity {

    private TextView textView; 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        runUdpServer();
    }

    private void runUdpServer() {
            String lText;
            byte[] lMsg = new byte[1500];
            DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(lMsg, lMsg.length);
            DatagramSocket ds = null;
            try {
                ds = new DatagramSocket(11112);
                ds.setBroadcast(true);
                //disable timeout for testing
                ds.setSoTimeout(100000);


                ds.receive(dp);


            } catch (SocketException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (ds != null) {
                    ds.close();
                }
            }

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                  runUdpServer();

         }


       private void runUdpServer() {
        String lText;
        byte[] lMsg = new byte[1500];
        DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(lMsg, lMsg.length);
        DatagramSocket ds = null;
        try {
            ds = new DatagramSocket(11112);
            ds.setBroadcast(true);
            //disable timeout for testing
            ds.setSoTimeout(100000);


            ds.receive(dp);


        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (ds != null) {
                ds.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call `DatagramSocket.receive()` in an `Activity` on the main (UI) thread. This method blocks until data is available. This will block the main (UI) thread and your app will be killed by Android with an ANR (Application Not Responding).

I assume that the reason the 2 projects are behaving differently is that the project you downloaded from the web probably has a low `android:targetSdkVersion` specified in the manifest. That project will also be killed with an ANR if it blocks long enough. Your project probably has a higher `android:targetSdkVersion`, so you are getting an exception thrown right away because you are doing network I/O on the main (UI) thread. This exception was added in a later version of the SDK (API level 11, Android 3.0, Honeycomb).

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html